# Python-pptx, find special text and replace with image

Tags: python, python-3.x, powerpoint, python-pptx

I'm trying to replace text in PowerPoint slides with an image. For example, if I find `<graph1>` I would like to replace that text with the picture "picture2.png".

I found this code on another stack overflow:

```
img  = Image.open("file2.png") 

for slide in prs.slides:
        for shape in slide.shapes:
            if shape.has_text_frame:
                if ("<graph1>" in shape.text):
                    print("1")
                    pic = slide.shapes.add_picture(img, 0, 0)
                    print("2")
```

but I get this error:

```
   image_part = self._package.get_or_add_image_part(image_file)
  File "C:\Users\Guigui\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pptx\package.py", line 36, in get_or_add_image_part
    return self._image_parts.get_or_add_image_part(image_file)
  File "C:\Users\Guigui\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages    image = Image.from_file(image_file)
  File "C:\Users\Guigui\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pptx\parts\image.py", line 170, in from_file
    blob = image_file.read()
  File "C:\Users\Guigui\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 519, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: read
```

I tried some other solutions (e.g. the `add_image` funtion) but I have never found how I can replace text with images.

And to be honest, I don't understand the error in the terminal.

If someone has a solution, please let me know.

Thanks for your reading

Answer (score -1):

That doesn’t replace the text with a picture rather insert a picture at 0,0 if said string exists.

Are you just wanting to insert a picture if the text exists? Or are you wanting to replace, for example, the text with a picture and using the text box position/size for the inserted picture?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).